# Not able to see Hello World Lightning Web Component on salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

After push we have 
sfdx force:source:push[image]
but not able to see helloWorld component on Salesforce
[image]
custom tab is empty.

Comment: Why your code is in aura folder? It should be in lwc folder

Comment: lwc folder also has a code. but if I remove a component from aura then having an issue while pushing.

D:\salesforce component new start\mywork>sfdx force:source:push
=== Pushed Source
No results found

Comment: Have you added target in xml file?

Comment: @codeyinthecloud This is not a LWC question, it's a mistagged [tag:lightning-aura-components] question. You can tell because it's (a) in the aura folder, (b) has no errors on push, and (c) has the Aura format of code (LWC uses different metadata files and such).

Comment: @sfdcfox my bad I haven’t looked close enough.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud No worries, just thought I'd let you know. Once you play with LWC a bit, you'll be able to spot the differences, since they're totally different file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today to develop Lightning Web Components, you need to use the pre-release version of the Salesforce CLI. Try running the following: `install salesforcedx@pre-release`

I don’t think you have the pre-release version installed, as lwc aren’t found and pushed when you run force:source:push.

To be sure which version of the CLI you’re using, just run `sfdx plugins --core`

Comment: These all...
@salesforce/plugin-generator 1.0.1 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 1.0.8 (core)
builtins 1.0.0 (core)
salesforcedx 45.0.12 (pre-release)

Comment: it's found push but nothing return. something just like this.

after i use this command "sfdx force:source:push"
i am getting the result this, 
=== Pushed Source
No results found

i am following these steps
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component

Comment: Can you try under your project folder to go to .sfdx/orgs, delete everything in there and try again ?

Comment: This is not a LWC question.

Comment: In one of the comments, Vaishali said there is also code in the lwc folder, so I thought that only the aura bundle is pushed. I had the issue after an sfdx update that removed my pre-release version of the CLI, lwc was there but never pushed to the server. Still not sure about the question though.